# Android lock widget available?

Tags: android, widget, locking

I'd like to add a lock widget to my application but I am unable to find one.

The android 4.4 alarm clock for example has one. Or the android lock screen. Are there similar components available as widgets which can be dragged into a layout in eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

The widget is called GlowPad and is part of the Android 4.4.4 AlarmClock.

I ended up using net.frakbot.glowpadbackport.GlowPadView.java, which is available at github.
I've ignored the readme.md, the gradlew (which is some kind of non-working makefile) and all the crap that came with it[1]. Instead I've created an android project from scratch with scr.frakbot/*, an empty AndroidManifest  ,  values/attrs.xml and lib/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar and it. And it worked out of the box.

[1] Don't get me wrong, gradle is a nice software, but why should I care creating a gradle.local, a keystore from keystore.example (!) and all that, if I can simply drop the 9 necessary files into eclipse?